# Get rid of all commas from each cell of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

Say I have a dataframe as follows:

```
d = {'col1': ['hello','nice to meet you', 'i like pudding, apples, bananas' ], 'col2': ['good','nice,cool','awesome']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Whereever there is a comma in a cell of the data, I would like to subset the string to become everything before the comma. For example

```
df.iloc[2,0] #should read "i like pudding" 
df.iloc[1,1] #should read "nice"
```

I have tried np.where() and subsetting the strings, but in my real dataframe, this becomes complicated with multiple occurrences of the same string. Is there a simple way to go over all cells, check for a comma, and subset that string to only contain the characters before the first comma?

Comment: `df.replace(regex={r'\,': ''})`?

Comment: @wwnde I think this just eliminates commas. I want to subset the whole string to only take what is before the first comma

Comment: Ok, lets try `df=df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('\,').str[0])`

Comment: @wwnde Did it work on your end? Mine is still returning the original dataframe

Comment: Try`df=df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('\,').str[0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split each cell by comma, then keep the first string.

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.split(',')[0])
```

Comment: Does this replace each cell with only the characters before the first comma? Or does it simply eliminate the comma.

Comment: modified the answer to not replace the comma, but keep the words before comma. You need to rephrase your question